# Rubygame + OSX hello world crashes at startup

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygame

I have this crash-at-startup problem with rubygame and OSX.

Anybody knows what might be causing it, and how to fix it?

Versions: OSX 10.5.7, ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [i686-darwin9], rubygame 2.5.3 installed from a rubygem, most software installed with MacPorts (up to date).

Different versions of ruby and rubygame seem to have identical problem. Googling doesn't help. Pygame works on the same machine, so SDL as such should be fine. Any ideas? Here's the stack trace.

$ ruby -e 'require "rubygems"; require "rubygame"; Rubygame.init'
        2009-07-30 18:13:20.416 ruby[66473:10b] *** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x116ebb0 of class NSCFNumber autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
        Stack: (0x95a58f0f 0x95965442 0x9493c309 0x95e818b8 0x95e80239 0x95e906d6 0x94998753 0x94996959 0x9499669e 0x9499604d 0x94995b8c 0x94993b88 0x6546a6 0x64a65b 0x61e670 0x61e6a7 0xa2e89 0x10b972 0x10c57c 0x109eb7 0x119d27 0x119d66 0x119d9a)
        2009-07-30 18:13:20.418 ruby[66473:10b]**  _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x116f030 of class NSCFNumber autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
        Stack: (0x95a58f0f 0x95965442 0x9493c341 0x95e818b8 0x95e80239 0x95e906d6 0x94998753 0x94996959 0x9499669e 0x9499604d 0x94995b8c 0x94993b88 0x6546a6 0x64a65b 0x61e670 0x61e6a7 0xa2e89 0x10b972 0x10c57c 0x109eb7 0x119d27 0x119d66 0x119d9a)
        2009-07-30 18:13:20.418 ruby[66473:10b]  **_NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x116f6e0 of class NSCFNumber autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
        Stack: (0x95a58f0f 0x95965442 0x9493c37b 0x95e818b8 0x95e80239 0x95e906d6 0x94998753 0x94996959 0x9499669e 0x9499604d 0x94995b8c 0x94993b88 0x6546a6 0x64a65b 0x61e670 0x61e6a7 0xa2e89 0x10b972 0x10c57c 0x109eb7 0x119d27 0x119d66 0x119d9a)
        2009-07-30 18:13:20.419 ruby[66473:10b]**  _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x116f340 of class NSCFDictionary autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
        Stack: (0x95a58f0f 0x95965442 0x9493c3de 0x95e818b8 0x95e80239 0x95e906d6 0x94998753 0x94996959 0x9499669e 0x9499604d 0x94995b8c 0x94993b88 0x6546a6 0x64a65b 0x61e670 0x61e6a7 0xa2e89 0x10b972 0x10c57c 0x109eb7 0x119d27 0x119d66 0x119d9a)
        2009-07-30 18:13:20.420 ruby[66473:10b]  **_NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0xa05ceb84 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
        Stack: (0x95a58f0f 0x95965442 0x9493c444 0x95e818b8 0x95e80239 0x95e906d6 0x94998753 0x94996959 0x9499669e 0x9499604d 0x94995b8c 0x94993b88 0x6546a6 0x64a65b 0x61e670 0x61e6a7 0xa2e89 0x10b972 0x10c57c 0x109eb7 0x119d27 0x119d66 0x119d9a)
        2009-07-30 18:13:20.421 ruby[66473:10b]**  _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x116fa90 of class NSCFNumber autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
        Stack: (0x95a58f0f 0x95965442 0x95967b6a 0x9493c48d 0x95e818b8 0x95e80239 0x95e906d6 0x94998753 0x94996959 0x9499669e 0x9499604d 0x94995b8c 0x94993b88 0x6546a6 0x64a65b 0x61e670 0x61e6a7 0xa2e89 0x10b972 0x10c57c 0x109eb7 0x119d27 0x119d66 0x119d9a)
        2009-07-30 18:13:20.422 ruby[66473:10b]  **_NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0xa05ceb94 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
        Stack: (0x95a58f0f 0x95965442 0x9493c444 0x95e818b8 0x95e80239 0x95e906d6 0x94998753 0x94996959 0x9499669e 0x9499604d 0x94995b8c 0x94993b88 0x6546a6 0x64a65b 0x61e670 0x61e6a7 0xa2e89 0x10b972 0x10c57c 0x109eb7 0x119d27 0x119d66 0x119d9a)
        2009-07-30 18:13:20.423 ruby[66473:10b]**  _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x116f6f0 of class NSCFNumber autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
        Stack: (0x95a58f0f 0x95965442 0x95967b6a 0x9493c48d 0x95e818b8 0x95e80239 0x95e906d6 0x94998753 0x94996959 0x9499669e 0x9499604d 0x94995b8c 0x94993b88 0x6546a6 0x64a65b 0x61e670 0x61e6a7 0xa2e89 0x10b972 0x10c57c 0x109eb7 0x119d27 0x119d66 0x119d9a)
        2009-07-30 18:13:20.423 ruby[66473:10b]  **_NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0xa05ceba4 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
        Stack: (0x95a58f0f 0x95965442 0x9493c444 0x95e818b8 0x95e80239 0x95e906d6 0x94998753 0x94996959 0x9499669e 0x9499604d 0x94995b8c 0x94993b88 0x6546a6 0x64a65b 0x61e670 0x61e6a7 0xa2e89 0x10b972 0x10c57c 0x109eb7 0x119d27 0x119d66 0x119d9a)
        2009-07-30 18:13:20.424 ruby[66473:10b]**  _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x116aac0 of class NSCFNumber autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
        Stack: (0x95a58f0f 0x95965442 0x95967b6a 0x9493c48d 0x95e818b8 0x95e80239 0x95e906d6 0x94998753 0x94996959 0x9499669e 0x9499604d 0x94995b8c 0x94993b88 0x6546a6 0x64a65b 0x61e670 0x61e6a7 0xa2e89 0x10b972 0x10c57c 0x109eb7 0x119d27 0x119d66 0x119d9a)
        2009-07-30 18:13:20.425 ruby[66473:10b]  **_NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0xa05cebb4 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
        Stack: (0x95a58f0f 0x95965442 0x9493c444 0x95e818b8 0x95e80239 0x95e906d6 0x94998753 0x94996959 0x9499669e 0x9499604d 0x94995b8c 0x94993b88 0x6546a6 0x64a65b 0x61e670 0x61e6a7 0xa2e89 0x10b972 0x10c57c 0x109eb7 0x119d27 0x119d66 0x119d9a)
        2009-07-30 18:13:20.426 ruby[66473:10b]**  _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x116aac0 of class NSCFNumber autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
        Stack: (0x95a58f0f 0x95965442 0x95967b6a 0x9493c48d 0x95e818b8 0x95e80239 0x95e906d6 0x94998753 0x94996959 0x9499669e 0x9499604d 0x94995b8c 0x94993b88 0x6546a6 0x64a65b 0x61e670 0x61e6a7 0xa2e89 0x10b972 0x10c57c 0x109eb7 0x119d27 0x119d66 0x119d9a)
        2009-07-30 18:13:20.427 ruby[66473:10b]  **_NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0xa05ceba4 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
        Stack: (0x95a58f0f 0x95965442 0x9493c444 0x95e818b8 0x95e80239 0x95e906d6 0x94998753 0x94996959 0x9499669e 0x9499604d 0x94995b8c 0x94993b88 0x6546a6 0x64a65b 0x61e670 0x61e6a7 0xa2e89 0x10b972 0x10c57c 0x109eb7 0x119d27 0x119d66 0x119d9a)
        2009-07-30 18:13:20.428 ruby[66473:10b]**  _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0xa05cebb4 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
        Stack: (0x95a58f0f 0x95965442 0x9493c444 0x95e818b8 0x95e80239 0x95e906d6 0x94998753 0x94996959 0x9499669e 0x9499604d 0x94995b8c 0x94993b88 0x6546a6 0x64a65b 0x61e670 0x61e6a7 0xa2e89 0x10b972 0x10c57c 0x109eb7 0x119d27 0x119d66 0x119d9a)
        2009-07-30 18:13:20.428 ruby[66473:10b]  **_NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0xa05ceba4 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
        Stack: (0x95a58f0f 0x95965442 0x9493c444 0x95e818b8 0x95e80239 0x95e906d6 0x94998753 0x94996959 0x9499669e 0x9499604d 0x94995b8c 0x94993b88 0x6546a6 0x64a65b 0x61e670 0x61e6a7 0xa2e89 0x10b972 0x10c57c 0x109eb7 0x119d27 0x119d66 0x119d9a)
        2009-07-30 18:13:20.429 ruby[66473:10b]**  _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0xa05cebb4 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
        Stack: (0x95a58f0f 0x95965442 0x9493c444 0x95e818b8 0x95e80239 0x95e906d6 0x94998753 0x94996959 0x9499669e 0x9499604d 0x94995b8c 0x94993b88 0x6546a6 0x64a65b 0x61e670 0x61e6a7 0xa2e89 0x10b972 0x10c57c 0x109eb7 0x119d27 0x119d66 0x119d9a)
        2009-07-30 18:13:20.430 ruby[66473:10b]  **_NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0xa05ceba4 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
        Stack: (0x95a58f0f 0x95965442 0x9493c444 0x95e818b8 0x95e80239 0x95e906d6 0x94998753 0x94996959 0x9499669e 0x9499604d 0x94995b8c 0x94993b88 0x6546a6 0x64a65b 0x61e670 0x61e6a7 0xa2e89 0x10b972 0x10c57c 0x109eb7 0x119d27 0x119d66 0x119d9a)
        2009-07-30 18:13:20.430 ruby[66473:10b]**  _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0xa05ceba4 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
        Stack: (0x95a58f0f 0x95965442 0x9493c444 0x95e818b8 0x95e80239 0x95e906d6 0x94998753 0x94996959 0x9499669e 0x9499604d 0x94995b8c 0x94993b88 0x6546a6 0x64a65b 0x61e670 0x61e6a7 0xa2e89 0x10b972 0x10c57c 0x109eb7 0x119d27 0x119d66 0x119d9a)
        2009-07-30 18:13:20.431 ruby[66473:10b]  **_NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0xa05ceba4 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
        Stack: (0x95a58f0f 0x95965442 0x9493c444 0x95e818b8 0x95e80239 0x95e906d6 0x94998753 0x94996959 0x9499669e 0x9499604d 0x94995b8c 0x94993b88 0x6546a6 0x64a65b 0x61e670 0x61e6a7 0xa2e89 0x10b972 0x10c57c 0x109eb7 0x119d27 0x119d66 0x119d9a)
        2009-07-30 18:13:20.432 ruby[66473:10b]**  _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x115bce0 of class NSCFNumber autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
        Stack: (0x95a58f0f 0x95965442 0x9493c55d 0x95e818b8 0x95e80239 0x95e906d6 0x94998753 0x94996959 0x9499669e 0x9499604d 0x94995b8c 0x94993b88 0x6546a6 0x64a65b 0x61e670 0x61e6a7 0xa2e89 0x10b972 0x10c57c 0x109eb7 0x119d27 0x119d66 0x119d9a)
        2009-07-30 18:13:20.434 ruby[66473:10b]  **_NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x11703f0 of class __NSFontTypefaceInfo autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
        Stack: (0x95a58f0f 0x95965442 0x9495240e 0x94952280 0x94951b27 0x94999773 0x94998753 0x94996959 0x9499669e 0x9499604d 0x94995b8c 0x94993b88 0x6546a6 0x64a65b 0x61e670 0x61e6a7 0xa2e89 0x10b972 0x10c57c 0x109eb7 0x119d27 0x119d66 0x119d9a)
        2009-07-30 18:13:20.435 ruby[66473:10b]**  _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x1171450 of class NSAffineTransform autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
        Stack: (0x95a58f0f 0x95965442 0x94952916 0x95e818b8 0x95e80239 0x95e906d6 0x94951d3a 0x94999773 0x94998753 0x94996959 0x9499669e 0x9499604d 0x94995b8c 0x94993b88 0x6546a6 0x64a65b 0x61e670 0x61e6a7 0xa2e89 0x10b972 0x10c57c 0x109eb7 0x119d27 0x119d66 0x119d9a)
        2009-07-30 18:13:20.436 ruby[66473:10b]  **_NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x1171900 of class NSFont autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
        Stack: (0x95a58f0f 0x95965442 0x94952842 0x94951d3a 0x94999773 0x94998753 0x94996959 0x9499669e 0x9499604d 0x94995b8c 0x94993b88 0x6546a6 0x64a65b 0x61e670 0x61e6a7 0xa2e89 0x10b972 0x10c57c 0x109eb7 0x119d27 0x119d66 0x119d9a)
        2009-07-30 18:13:20.436 ruby[66473:10b]**  _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x1171a40 of class NSFont autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
        Stack: (0x95a58f0f 0x95965442 0x94951e07 0x94999773 0x94998753 0x94996959 0x9499669e 0x9499604d 0x94995b8c 0x94993b88 0x6546a6 0x64a65b 0x61e670 0x61e6a7 0xa2e89 0x10b972 0x10c57c 0x109eb7 0x119d27 0x119d66 0x119d9a)
        2009-07-30 18:13:20.438 ruby[66473:10b]  **_NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x11726b0 of class NSCFArray autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
        Stack: (0x95a58f0f 0x95965442 0x9499f9fa 0x9499f91b 0x9499f85b 0x9499f648 0x94993bee 0x6546a6 0x64a65b 0x61e670 0x61e6a7 0xa2e89 0x10b972 0x10c57c 0x109eb7 0x119d27 0x119d66 0x119d9a)
        2009-07-30 18:13:20.439 ruby[66473:10b]**  _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x11735f0 of class NSCFSet autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
        Stack: (0x95a58f0f 0x95965442 0x90135eb0 0x9499fb66 0x9499f91b 0x9499f85b 0x9499f648 0x94993bee 0x6546a6 0x64a65b 0x61e670 0x61e6a7 0xa2e89 0x10b972 0x10c57c 0x109eb7 0x119d27 0x119d66 0x119d9a)
        2009-07-30 18:13:20.440 ruby[66473:10b]  **_NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x11737d0 of class NSCFArray autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
        Stack: (0x95a58f0f 0x95965442 0x9013601f 0x9499fb66 0x9499f91b 0x9499f85b 0x9499f648 0x94993bee 0x6546a6 0x64a65b 0x61e670 0x61e6a7 0xa2e89 0x10b972 0x10c57c 0x109eb7 0x119d27 0x119d66 0x119d9a)
        2009-07-30 18:13:20.441 ruby[66473:10b]**  _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x11738b0 of class NSCFArray autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
        Stack: (0x95a58f0f 0x95965442 0x90135118 0x9499f961 0x9499f85b 0x9499f648 0x94993bee 0x6546a6 0x64a65b 0x61e670 0x61e6a7 0xa2e89 0x10b972 0x10c57c 0x109eb7 0x119d27 0x119d66 0x119d9a)
        2009-07-30 18:13:20.441 ruby[66473:10b]  **_NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x1171a40 of class NSFont autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
        Stack: (0x95a58f0f 0x95965442 0x94951a41 0x9499f882 0x9499f648 0x94993bee 0x6546a6 0x64a65b 0x61e670 0x61e6a7 0xa2e89 0x10b972 0x10c57c 0x109eb7 0x119d27 0x119d66 0x119d9a)
        2009-07-30 18:13:20.443 ruby[66473:10b]**  _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0xa001ce20 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
        Stack: (0x95a58f0f 0x95965442 0x95983c08 0x94965d1c 0x949a0b2d 0x949a056e 0x949a03e6 0x949a0317 0x949a01b7 0x9499f8a7 0x9499f648 0x94993bee 0x6546a6 0x64a65b 0x61e670 0x61e6a7 0xa2e89 0x10b972 0x10c57c 0x109eb7 0x119d27 0x119d66 0x119d9a)
        2009-07-30 18:13:20.444 ruby[66473:10b]  **_NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0xa00159a0 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
        Stack: (0x95a58f0f 0x95965442 0x95983c08 0x94965d1c 0x949a0c36 0x949a0590 0x949a03e6 0x949a0317 0x949a01b7 0x9499f8a7 0x9499f648 0x94993bee 0x6546a6 0x64a65b 0x61e670 0x61e6a7 0xa2e89 0x10b972 0x10c57c 0x109eb7 0x119d27 0x119d66 0x119d9a)
        2009-07-30 18:13:20.444 ruby[66473:10b]**  _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x114c300 of class NSCFNumber autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
        Stack: (0x95a58f0f 0x95965442 0x949a0670 0x949a03e6 0x949a0317 0x949a01b7 0x9499f8a7 0x9499f648 0x94993bee 0x6546a6 0x64a65b 0x61e670 0x61e6a7 0xa2e89 0x10b972 0x10c57c 0x109eb7 0x119d27 0x119d66 0x119d9a)
        2009-07-30 18:13:20.445 ruby[66473:10b]  **_NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x1175390 of class NSCalibratedWhiteColor autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
        Stack: (0x95a58f0f 0x95965442 0x94aafba3 0x94aafaa3 0x94aaf17b 0x94aaed97 0x949a0294 0x9499f8a7 0x9499f648 0x94993bee 0x6546a6 0x64a65b 0x61e670 0x61e6a7 0xa2e89 0x10b972 0x10c57c 0x109eb7 0x119d27 0x119d66 0x119d9a)
        2009-07-30 18:13:20.446 ruby[66473:10b]**  _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x1175630 of class NSCFArray autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
        Stack: (0x95a58f0f 0x95965442 0x9499f9fa 0x94ab2773 0x94ab255b 0x94ab0f6a 0x94ab0d1d 0x9499f661 0x94993bee 0x6546a6 0x64a65b 0x61e670 0x61e6a7 0xa2e89 0x10b972 0x10c57c 0x109eb7 0x119d27 0x119d66 0x119d9a)
        2009-07-30 18:13:20.447 ruby[66473:10b]  **_NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x11756f0 of class NSCFSet autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
        Stack: (0x95a58f0f 0x95965442 0x90135eb0 0x9499fb66 0x94ab2773 0x94ab255b 0x94ab0f6a 0x94ab0d1d 0x9499f661 0x94993bee 0x6546a6 0x64a65b 0x61e670 0x61e6a7 0xa2e89 0x10b972 0x10c57c 0x109eb7 0x119d27 0x119d66 0x119d9a)
        2009-07-30 18:13:20.447 ruby[66473:10b] *** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x1175650 of class NSCFArray autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
        Stack: (0x95a58f0f 0x95965442 0x9013601f 0x9499fb66 0x94ab2773 0x94ab255b 0x94ab0f6a 0x94ab0d1d 0x9499f661 0x94993bee 0x6546a6 0x64a65b 0x61e670 0x61e6a7 0xa2e89 0x10b972 0x10c57c 0x109eb7 0x119d27 0x119d66 0x119d9a)
        2009-07-30 18:13:20.448 ruby[66473:10b] *** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x1175b20 of class NSCFDictionary autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
        Stack: (0x95a58f0f 0x95965442 0x9013c27e 0x94ab5606 0x94ab53fd 0x94ab0d92 0x9499f661 0x94993bee 0x6546a6 0x64a65b 0x61e670 0x61e6a7 0xa2e89 0x10b972 0x10c57c 0x109eb7 0x119d27 0x119d66 0x119d9a)

Answer (score 0):

You'll note on OS X the requirements include rsdl (which is itself an executable).

http://docs.rubygame.org/rdoc/current/

So after installing that try:

rsdl foogame.rb